# Calling ActionResult from PartialView never hits

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

Pretty new with MVC and going through a few tutorials. Have done the following:

Add a controller called CustomerController.
Add 2 methods

```
    public ActionResult Render()
    {
        // Go to a third party WebAPI and get the results in a List
       return PartialView("CustomerList", custList);
    }

    public ActionResult SomeTest()
    {
        Response.Redirect("Somepage");
    }
```

I then add a page (`LandingView.cshtml`) and create a `PartialView` called `CustomerList` and add the below code to the LandingView page

```
@Html.Action("Render", "Customer")
```

When i view this page it renders the page with a list of customers. The HTML for the `PartialView` is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeTest", "Customer"))
{

    <div class="container">
        @foreach (var i in Model)
        {
            <a href="@i.Url">
                <div class="product-grid__item__name">@i.Title</div><br />
                <div class="product-grid__item__price">@i.Price.ToString("C")</div>
            </a>
             
            <input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Go" />
        }
    </div>
}
```

When i click the button it never hits the SomeTest method? In debug mode i have put a breakpoint on `Render` and `SomeTest`, Render hits on page load but when clicking Go it never hits the SomeTest method?

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 'type' attribute value of the input element to "submit" not "button".  This will trigger the form submission on click.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnGo" value="Go" />
```

You may experience some build errors because the SomeTest() controller method is expecting a return value of type ActionResult.

Comment: Thanks! Yes i knew about that error i was trying to get the method to hit so added some basic code to try and narrow it down